# Sort values that have the most distinct values in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

Hello i have the following pandas dataframe and I'm trying to find a way to sort the values that have the most distinct values for a certain field (ie. "source_name"):

```
import pandas as pd

df_test=pd.DataFrame()
df_test['hotel_name']=['hotel1','hotel1','hotel2','hotel2','hotel2','hotel3','hotel3','hotel4','hotel4','hotel4']
df_test['source_name']=['source1','source2','source1','source2','source3','source1','source1','source1','source2','source3']
```

At the moment, I'm doing the following but it's just counting the number of hotel names, whereas I want to sort by the number of distinct values for the "hotel_name" field.

```
output = df_test.groupby(['hotel_name']).apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records'))

s = output.str.count("source_name").sort_values(ascending=False).index
```

My expected output would be a dict with the keys being in the following order:

```
hotel2, hotel4, hotel1, hotel3
```

Comment: how looks expected dict?

Comment: The dictionary keys are never ordered.

Comment: Dictionaries in python are insert order sorted ....

Comment: @MayankPorwal since python 3.7 they are ;)

Comment: What would be the values of the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

So if need sorted columns with ascending order use:

```
#sort by counts    
df = df_test.sort_values('hotel_name',key=lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()),ascending=False)

#sort by unique counts   
s = df_test.groupby('hotel_name')['source_name'].nunique()
df = df_test.sort_values('hotel_name', key=lambda x: x.map(s), ascending=False)

print (df)
  hotel_name source_name
2     hotel2     source1
3     hotel2     source2
4     hotel2     source3
7     hotel4     source1
8     hotel4     source2
9     hotel4     source3
0     hotel1     source1
1     hotel1     source2
5     hotel3     source1
6     hotel3     source1
```

Then add `sort=False` for avoid default sorting of new sorted `DataFrame`:

```
out = df.groupby(['hotel_name'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records')).to_dict()
                                                  
print (out)
{'hotel2': '[{"hotel_name":"hotel2","source_name":"source1"},{"hotel_name":"hotel2","source_name":"source2"},{"hotel_name":"hotel2","source_name":"source3"}]', 'hotel4': '[{"hotel_name":"hotel4","source_name":"source1"},{"hotel_name":"hotel4","source_name":"source2"},{"hotel_name":"hotel4","source_name":"source3"}]', 'hotel1': '[{"hotel_name":"hotel1","source_name":"source1"},{"hotel_name":"hotel1","source_name":"source2"}]', 'hotel3': '[{"hotel_name":"hotel3","source_name":"source1"},{"hotel_name":"hotel3","source_name":"source1"}]'}
```

Comment: thanks, now how can i use the groupby with the right order for the keys now? output = df_test.groupby(['hotel_name']).apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records'))

Comment: @oli - Use `df_test.groupby(['hotel_name'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.to_json(orient='records')) `

Comment: You have clearly the right answer! not me...

Comment: @Corralien - Ya, it was not clear what are values in dicts.

Answer (score 1):

Use `value_counts`:

```
>>> df.value_counts('hotel_name').index.tolist()
['hotel2', 'hotel4', 'hotel1', 'hotel3']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to have a dictionary as an output with the `Hotel` as key and the values as the number of unique hotels then you should use `OrderedDict`:

```
output = df_test.groupby(['hotel_name'])['source_name'].nunique().sort_values(ascending=False)
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(output.to_dict())
```

Which outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('hotel4', 3), ('hotel2', 3), ('hotel1', 2), ('hotel3', 1)])
```

If you only want the `hotel` values:

```
output.index
```

Outputs:

```
Index(['hotel4', 'hotel2', 'hotel1', 'hotel3'], dtype='object', name='hotel_name')
```